How to create desktop icon to open python3 shell and run .py in the background?
OSX 12.7.6 Python 3
I have  a file RGB_plot.py that I want to run in Python shell, with the terminal window staying hidden, using a shortcut on my desk top.
I have tried the shortcut.app with no luck. I've search here and elsewhere for some idea on how to do this , also with no luck.
I presently open the file in VSC, copy, open terminal, shell to Python3, then paste. This generates a 3D graph plot which pulls data from .xlsx
Is there a way to just click on a desktop icon and make it run?

Create a .bat file containing pythonw "C:\path\to\script.py". Use pythonw to run the script without a visible console. Create a shortcut to the .bat file on the desktop, set it to run minimized, and customize the icon.

OP is asking about macos, not windows.

I must be missing something, or maybe because the answer above was for Windows. OSX 12.7, I have tried                    pythonw“C:\Users\stanbrown\Desktop\Plot\RGB_plot.py” as my path on one line, preceded by#!/bin/bash . I have save as .bash .bat and even .sh . All double clicking does is bring it up in VSC. What amI (still) doing wrong
